# Classifying the critical points when second derivative test fails.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x, y) = x^4 + y^4 - x^3$$

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= 4y^3 = 0 \implies y = 0\\
    \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= 4x^3 - 3x^2 = 0 \implies \text{ either } x = 0 \text{ or } x = \frac{3}{4}
\end{align*}
Hence, $\left(0, 0 \right) $ and $ \left( \frac{3}{4}, 0 \right) $ are critical points. The Hessian is $H(x, y) = \begin{bmatrix}
12 x^2 - 6x & 0\\
0 & 12y^2
\end{bmatrix}$.

$H(0, 0) = \textbf{0}$ so no conclusion.

$H\left ( \frac{3}{4}, 0 \right ) = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{9}{4} & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ hence the test is inconclusive.

Are they any other ways I can find the nature of critical points: local min, local max or saddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $f(x,y) \ge f(x,0)$.  What does the graph of $f(x,0)$ look like?

Comment: the graph of $f(x, 0)$ shows that $(0, 0)$ is a saddle point and $\left( \frac{3}{4}, 0 \right) $ is a local min. But I want to understand the general principle. Given the information that a point $(x_0, y_0)$ is a critical point (and the second derivative test fails), is it just enough to cut the graph of $f(x, y)$ by any vertical plane passing through $(x_0, y_0)$ and doing the analysis in one variable??

Comment: or maybe this is not a general principle, it only worked here because of $f(x, y) \geq f(x, 0)$.

Comment: @ironX Correct.  Without $f(x,y) \ge f(x,0)$ it can be harder.

Answer (score 1):

Second derivatives are of limited help, particular with functions of two or more variables with power-functions with exponents larger than $ \ 2 \ . $  When the Hessian is just giving you zero at a point, it is often useful to go back to the properties of the function to see what issues are arising.

In the $ \ xz-$ plane, the function is $ \ f(0, y) \ =  \ y^4 \ , $ which you know is always "concave upward".  What causes a problem for the Hessian is that this is a curve with a very "flat" minimum, so using a second derivative doesn't probe behavior at the origin "deeply" enough (you have the same difficulty in single-variable calculus).  But in the neighborhood of $ \ ( 0,0) \ , $ we see that  $ \ f_{yy} \ = \ 12y^2 \ \ge \ 0 \ . $

In the $ \ yz-$ plane, however, we have  $ \ f(x, 0) \ =  \ x^4 \ - \ x^3 \ , $ for which there is an inflection point at the origin along the $ \ x-$ direction.  With $ \ f_{xx} \ = \ 6x · (2x - 1) \ , $ the concavity switches from positive for $ \ x \ < \ 0 \ $ to negative for $ \ 0 \ < \ x \ < \ \frac12 \ , $ then back to positive for $ \ x \ > \ \frac12 \ . $  So close to the origin, the sign of the curvature of the surface changes:  the surface has a "ripple in the bottom" and there is a small region over which $ \ f(x, y) \ < \ 0 \ . $  Hence, the origin is a saddle point.

This is not something that will be picked up by simply evaluating the Hessian at $ \ (0,0) \ ; $ it would be better to investigate the determinant *function*  $ \ 72x · (2x - 1) · y^2 \ . $

[The other point that you found, $ \ \left( \frac34 \ , \ 0 \right) \ , $ is sitting in a neighborhood where $ \ f_{xx} \ $ and $ \ f_{yy} \ $ are both positive, so the surface curvature is positive there and you presumably found this to be the location of the absolute minimum for the function.]